# Invalid or missing api_id in clickatell

Tags: web, laravel-5, sms-gateway, clickatell

i am trying to integrate clickatell  SMS gateway in my web system. i make free test account on clickatell and create SMS REST integrations , from SMS REST integrations i get API key , am use this api key in http://api.clickatell.com/http/auth?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&api_id=API_KEY
but i am getting this error "ERR: 108, Invalid or missing api_id".Please help me in getting valid API key , 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

API keys only apply to the REST API. You have an 'HTTP API' URL there. Within your central account, you will see example REST API cURL commands that you can use, as well as example commands for an HTTP API.

Comment: i have also try to use clickatell library like this $clickatell = new ClickatellRest('API_KEY');
$response = $clickatell->sendMessage(array("923008537239"), "My Message");
var_dump($response);  Now this error   come {"code":"001","description":"Authentication failed","documentation":"http://www.clickatell.com/help/apidocs/error/001.htm"}

Comment: please help me @whaterver_sa

Comment: In that case, you should use the long auth token from your REST API. Its typically around 80 characters long.